# Resolving dependency based on custom criteria

Tags: autofac

My app relies on multiple event bus objects which are basic publish/subscribe notification model (http://caliburn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator).

What I want to do is share certain an instance of aggregators with a groups of components. Say component I have a single event bus that's shared between component A, B, and C, and then another event bus that's shared between D,E,F.

I essentially want to declare the event busses as singleton and inject them based on some criteria. I kinda wanna avoid subtyping the event busses just for the purposes of distinguishing resolution.

I've used Google Guice IoC in java which allows metadata resolution for a parameter. Aka in java it allowed me to something equivalent to this.

Example:

```
public A([SpecialUseAggregator]IEventAggregator something)
public B([SpecialUseAggregator]IEventAggregator something)

public E([AnotherUseAggregator]IEventAggregator something)
public F([AnotherUseAggregator]IEventAggregator something)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autofac does not have/use attributes for the registration. One solution is to use the [Named/Keyed](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices) registration feature.

So you need to need to register you two `EventAggreator` with different names/keys and when registering your consumer types A,B, etc you can use the `WithParameter` to tell Autofac which `IEventAggreator` it should use for the given instance:

```cs
var contianerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
contianerBuilder.Register(c => CreateAndConfigureSpecialEventAggregator())
                        .Named<IEventAggreator>("SpecialUseAggregator");
contianerBuilder.Register(c => CreateAndConfigureAnotherUseAggregator())
                        .Named<IEventAggreator>("AnotherUseAggregator");

contianerBuilder.RegisterType<A>).AsSelf()
                 .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter
                 .ForNamed<IEventAggreator>("SpecialUseAggregator"));
contianerBuilder.RegisterType<B>().AsSelf()
                 .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter
                 .ForNamed<IEventAggreator>("SpecialUseAggregator"));
contianerBuilder.RegisterType<C>).AsSelf()
                 .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter
                 .ForNamed<IEventAggreator>("AnotherUseAggregator"));
contianerBuilder.RegisterType<D>().AsSelf()
                 .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter
                 .ForNamed<IEventAggreator>("AnotherUseAggregator"));
var container = contianerBuilder.Build();
```

I you still would like to use attributes then you can do it with Autofac because it has all the required extension points it just requires some more code to teach Autofac about your attribute and use it correctly.

If you are registering your types with scanning you cannot use the easily use the `WithParameter` registration however you use the [Metadata facility](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Metadata) in Autofac:

Just create an attribute which will hold your EventAggreator key:

```cs
public class EventAggrAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public EventAggrAttribute(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }
}
```

And attribute your classes:

```cs
[EventAggrAttribute("SpecialUseAggregator")]
public class AViewModel
{
    public AViewModel(IEventAggreator eventAggreator)
    {
    }
}
```

Then when you do the scanning you need to use the `WithMetadataFrom` to register the metadata:

```cs
contianerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
            .OnPreparing(Method)
            .WithMetadataFrom<EventAggrAttribute>();
```

And finally you need the `OnPreparing` event where you do the metadata based resolution:

```cs
private void Method(PreparingEventArgs obj)
{
    // Metadata["Key"] is coming from the EventAggrAttribute.Key
    var key = obj.Component.Metadata["Key"].ToString();
    ResolvedParameter resolvedParameter = 
        ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IEventAggreator>();
    obj.Parameters = new List<Parameter>() { resolvedParameter};
}
```

Here is [gist of a working unit test.](https://gist.github.com/nemesv/0ad4f1b3363102b6ad9f)

Comment: I saw the use of Named or Keyed resolutions, but that doesn't work for me as I want to inject them through constructor. Unless I'm mistaken you can't inject a keyed value without having a reference to the container, something I'm very against any of my classes having knowledge of. You mention it's possible with extra code in autofac - can you give a code sample on how that would work? I don't mind putting in the plumbing for attributes myself, but not sure how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean on "inject them through constructor". Your A,B classes still get the `IEventAggreator` through their constructor. And you don't need the reference the container to inject keyed value. To be clear: are your A,B classes viewmodels registered by convention in Caliburn? So thats why use you don't want to register them as keyed? Why do you need to have two different `IEventAggregator`? What is their purpose?

Comment: @macsux please check my updated answer. I hope that you can apply this info to your situation.

Comment: That sorta works for what I need. Still wish there was a way to hook into parameter level tagging which I found very convinient when working with google guice IoC container, but I guess this will do.

Comment: I'm not familiar with guice. But I think the parameter level tagging is not well supported in Autofac because it is somewhat against the inversion of control principle and you create additional coupling. So your A class should not know about the fact that multiple `IEventAggrator` implementation exist so you also should not tell which `IEventAggrator` to use when declaring A.

Comment: I look at attributes as hints that aren't necessarily part of the contract. But if the container can hook into the "hints" it allows for more advanced wiring scenarios. I disagree that it creates a dependency because it still doesn't know anything about implementation, just that IEventAggragator (or whatever interface you're expecting) is related to a certain logical grouping or related to a concern. Aka it's a hint to whoever passes the interface that it should pick one that if multiple available, pick one that addresses a particular concern